# How to get request and response size in gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

In Postman I can see  request and response size
[image]

How do I get this in gatling ?
I need to validate the size.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate size via `check` and `bodyLength` where pass expected size in bytes.

```
val request = http("request")
    .get("localhost")
    .check(
      bodyLength.is(221)
    )
```